# How to install Monaco font in PyCharm in Windows 10?

Tags: ide, pycharm

I have PyCharm 17.3 installed on my Windows 10. I have Monaco fonts installed in my system(.ttf file). Now I can't see it in settings with other fonts. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a check box next to fonts "Show monospaced fonts only". Just uncheck it and all the fonts installed will show up there.